# Set ios tabbar item programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I have four tab items that I set via storyboard but I have just one tab bar that I would like to set programmatically because I want that last tab bar item to be my profile picture. Is there a way I can set just that one tab bar item programmatically in the ProfileViewController without having to set the other three tab bar items programmatically.

I want to set this to the tabbar item but it is coming up blank:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tabBarItem.title = "MY ACCOUNT"
      //  self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "Speech Bubble Filled-50")

        if let postProfile = self.loggedInUserUid {

            let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((loggedInUserUid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")

            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.tabBarItem.image = image
                })

            }).resume()
}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A view controller can set its own tab image after being loaded from a storyboard. You can do it in `awakeFromNib`:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "star")
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: tab bar with star image]

You might want to do a better job than I did of sizing the image…

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. Even though I am able to get an image from my assets folder to show up, I can not get an image retrieved from firebase to be my tabbar image.

Comment: All updates to the UI need to happen on the main thread (or main queue). Are you sure the completion handler is called on the main thread?

Comment: yes because I used the same code to get the same picture to an image view and it was successful

Comment: That doesn't prove that it always runs on the main queue, or even that it ever runs on the main queue. The effect of updating the UI from a background queue is unpredictable. It may work in some circumstances and not others.

Comment: how would I go about making sure the image appears?

Comment: Dispatch back to the main queue to update the UI. There is a metric pantload of examples on stackoverflow and all over the web.

Comment: I have updated my question again but it is still not working

Comment: `UIImage(data:)` can return nil. Have you verified that it's not returning nil?

Comment: i checked it is not returning nil

Comment: Much better than most of the other solutions manually setting via tab index. Thanks!